# Maven: Naming of a copy of a project

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a project that consists of 3 subprojects.
I handle it with Maven in Eclipse.

```
MyPrj
  Server
    pom.xml with 
        <groupId>MyPrj</groupId>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <name>Server</name>
    src/main/java/MyPrj/Server/Server.java with 
        package MyPrj.Server
    
  Client
    pom.xml with
        <groupId>MyPrj</groupId>
        <artifactId>Client</artifactId>
        <name>Client</name>
    src/main/java/MyPrj/Client/Client.java with 
        package MyPrj.Client

  pom.xml with
    <groupId>MyPrj</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyPrj</artifactId>
    <name>MyPrj</name>
    <modules>
        <module>Server</module>
        <module>Client</module>
    </modules>
```

All is working fine.

Now I need to have a copy of MyPrj that should represent a newer version.
I did a copy of MyPrj.

```
MyPrj2
  Server
    pom.xml with 
        <groupId>MyPrj2</groupId>
        <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
        <name>Server</name>
    src/main/java/MyPrj2/Server/Server.java with 
        package MyPrj2.Server
    
  Client
    pom.xml with
        <groupId>MyPrj2</groupId>
        <artifactId>Client</artifactId>
        <name>Client</name>
    src/main/java/MyPrj2/Client/Client.java with 
        package MyPrj2.Client

  pom.xml with
    <groupId>MyPrj2</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyPrj2</artifactId>
    <name>MyPrj2</name>
    <modules>
        <module>Server</module>
        <module>Client</module>
    </modules>
```

I can compile and package it in Maven without a problem.
But if I try to import MyPrj2 in Eclipse (exsiting Maven project) it gets a problem with the subprojects (Client, Server).

I can not tick the subprojects ("Project Client is already imported into workspace").
So the dirtories are imported but they are not recognized as a Java project.

So must be some problem with the naming. But the groupId is clearly different.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If importing an existing Maven project you can select in Advanced a naming template.

I selected [groupid].[artifactid] there and then both projects were able to co-exist in eclipse.